# Does a classic ASP script keep executing after the browser runs out of graphical memory?

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic ASP script which manages hundreds of thousands of people's data. For each person it prints about 10 lines. After a while (let's say at about the 60k-th person) the browser runs out of memory (despite having enough RAM, in my case 1TB). Does the ASP keep executing or does it die with the browser? I cannot debug unfortunately.

Comment: Technically, once a script is executed in IIS, it will keep on running until the ScriptTimeout is exceeded or the script finishes, with or without a browser connection. A buffer overflow or any type of runtime error will stop it though.

Comment: Hold up .. you have 1 TB or RAM or 1 TB of hard drive storage ?  And the RAM is running out on the Client NOT the Server ..

Comment: Notes to improve performance - DO NOT MIX HTML AND ASP Classic code, <h2> <%=variable%></h2>   should instead be written Response.Write "<h2>"&variable&"</h2>" for it to run faster so it doesn't have to switch languages on each line.  And AVOID Concatenation when possible such as VARIABLE = "THING" (next line) VARIABLE = VARIABLE & NEWTHING (next line) VARIABLE = VARIABLE & NEWTHING .. those things SORELY slow your applications down.

Comment: The main issue you are going to have is the DOM handling the rendering of hundreds of thousands of details in the browser. Would definitely look at implementing an approach that paginates the data rather than trying to return everything.